# Sequential continuity implies continuity proof

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, functions, continuity

I had a few questions regarding this proof.

So to prove this, I have looked at the contrapositive method, so Suppose f is not continuous the if xn —> c then f(xn) does not converge to f(c)

The proof is as follows:

Since f is not continuous at c then for each n take δ = $\frac{1}{n}$ then we can find xn such that

|xn - c| < $\frac{1}{n}$ and |f(xn) - f(c)| $\ge$ ε

So we have that the above is not sequentially continuous.

So my questions were: why is δ = $\frac{1}{n}$. So how is this relevant, and why does this show that it is not sequentially continuous.

Can you please help me understand the proof?

Thank you :)

Comment: $\frac1n$ is not specifically relevant, you could take any sequence of positive numbers $\delta_n$ converging to $0,$ and associate similarly to it a sequence $(x_n)$ such that $|x_n-c|<\delta_n$ and $f(x_n)-f(c)|\le\varepsilon.$ It shows that $f$ is not sequentially continuous at $c$: look at the definition of sequential continuity and write formally its negation.

Comment: Sorry, i did not mean $f(x_n)-f(c)|\le\varepsilon$ but $|f(x_n)-f(c)|\ge\varepsilon.$

Comment: The contrapositive is: if $f$ is not continuous, then *there exists* a sequence $(x_n)$ such that $x_n\to c$ but $f(x_n)\not\to f(c)$. It is not: if $f$ is continuous, then *for every* sequence $(x_n)$ such that $x_n\to c$, we have $f(x_n)\not\to f(c)$.

Comment: @AnneBauval thank you for your reply. Why are we taking a sequence of δn that converges to 0 and how do we know such a sequence exists such that xn converges to c but f(xn) does not converge to f(c)?

Comment: Sorry, my earlier comment contains a typo. I meant to say in the second sentence "It is not: if $f$ is *not* continuous, then...".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(I suppose $f$ is defined on $\Bbb R.$)

A formal definition of "$f$ is continuous at $c$" is:
$$\forall\varepsilon>0\quad\exists\delta>0\quad\forall x\in\Bbb R\quad(|x-c|<\delta\Rightarrow|f(x)-f(c)|<\varepsilon)$$
hence a formal definition of "$f$ is not continuous at $c$" is:
$$\exists\varepsilon>0\quad\forall\delta>0\quad\exists x\in\Bbb R\quad(|x-c|<\delta\text{ and }|f(x)-f(c)|\ge\varepsilon).$$
Assuming this and taking such a (fixed) $\varepsilon,$ the trick is to apply this assumption to a sequence of positive $\delta_n$'s which tends to $0,$ and to name $x_n$ one of the $x$'s associated to $\delta_n$ by this assumption ($\forall\delta>0\quad\exists x\dots$). Since $|x_n-c|<\delta_n$ and $\delta_n\to0$ we get $x_n\to c,$ and since $|f(x_n)-f(c)|\ge\varepsilon$ we get $f(x_n)\not\to f(c).$ The conjunction of these two results prove that $f$ is not sequentially continuous at $c.$

Comment: why do we take δ tends to 0? And also to confirm if we take limits for |x-c| < δn we have 0 < lim (x-c) < 0 so by sandwich rule x tends to c right? 

And in this case it f(xn) tends to f(c) then we would have 0$\ge$ ε  which would be a contradiction since ε>0? So for this case we have found a δn such δ |x-c| < δn  and hence we have that x tends to c but f(xn) does not tend to f(c)?

Comment: Yes, we take $\delta_n\to0$ exactly to get the hypothesis of the sandwich rule. But you did not write this rule correctly. It is $0\le|x_n-c|<\delta_n$ so ($|x_n-c|\to0$, i.e.) $x_n\to c.$ I agree with your "And in this case [...] contradiction since ε>0" but I find a direct reasoning (not by contradiction) simpler here. I agree with the end of your comment.